# How to search a text efficient way in a text field? Spring Boot + JPA + PostgresSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

```
public class Post {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private Date createdAt;
}
```

content field is the text field. This field value actually is a Json object, I converted it to text.

How can search efficient way a text pattern match or not?

I want to implement using spring boot, JPA and postgresSQL

Comment: Can assume this is a JPA @Entity?

Comment: Yes. This is a JPA @Entity

Comment: And are you using a JPA Repository? Can you edit your question and add it please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FTS on postgres.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html

fts will provide searching similar to search engines but you need to configure it as per your need. it will be much faster than like/ilike '%query%'.

Answer (score 1):

If `content` is JSON, why not use native Postgres `json` (or `jsonb`) type for that field, and then search inside it using native [JSON operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html).

This should allow you to request on the actual value, instead of doing clunky text search on a `String` (and potentially even selecting unexpected data).

*e.g.*: if you want to request an ID in a `jsonb` field, you would do something like:

```sql
-- using JSON native operator, clean
select p.* from post p where p.content ->> 'id' = <ID>;
select p.* from post p where p.content ->> 'id' like '%PARTIAL_ID%';

-- using text field, clunky
select p.* from post p where p.content like '%"id": "<ID>"%';
```

Comment: Agreed, native json is much better than text. This can works as a native query in Springboot

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you have a JPA repository already.
All you need to do is add a method and add the JPQL as below.

```
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE p.content LIKE %:keyword%")
    List<Post> searchByContent(String keyword);
}
```

Then in your service:

```
@Service
public class PostService {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    public List<Post> searchByContent(String keyword) {
        return postRepository.searchByContent(keyword);
   
    }
}
```